H2 not recognizes parameters with coalesce() causing org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement [Unknown data type: "?"
In my Criteria Select API test I want to select from two joined DB tables. The WHERE condition uses two parameters pRefDateFrom and pRefDateTo. If these two parameters are used as first argument of the coalesce() function, hibernate does not resolve/replace the parameters. Hence the parameter placeholders "?" are kept in the SQL statement which lead to SQLExceptions when preparing the SQL statement. In my case (see Exception stack below):
select ... from member_new c1_0,visa_new v1_0 where ... and (? is null or ? is null) or v1_0.date_to is not null and v1_0.date_to between coalesce(?,?) and coalesce(?,?))

I migrated this test from SpringBoot2 to SpringBoot3 jumping over a couple of versions of Hibernate and H2 database. Now it is a SpringBoot3 Test Case where I am using h2:2.1.214 and hibernate-core:6.2.20.Final (within spring-boot-starter-jpa:3.1.8).
I had no problem with the coalesce() function and parameter replacement when using h2:1.4.200 and hibernate-core:5.6.14.Final (within spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.6.14).
@Test
@Transactional
void testLocalDateParameter() {

    // SELECT MEMBER_NEW.PERSON_ID
    // FROM MEMBER_NEW mem, VISA_NEW vis
    // WHERE MEMBER_NEW.ID = VISA_NEW.ID
    // AND ((DATE_TO IS NULL AND (:pRefDateFrom IS NULL OR :pRefDateTo IS NULL) OR
    //      (DATE_TO IS NOT NULL AND
    //       DATE_TO BETWEEN NVL(:pRefDateFrom, MinimumLocalDate)
    //                   AND NVL(:pRefDateTo, MaximumLocalDate)));

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> cq = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
    Root<MemberEntity> root = cq.from(MemberEntity.class);
    root.alias("mem");
    Root<VisaEntity> vis = cq.from(VisaEntity.class);
    vis.alias("vis");

    cq.multiselect(root.get(MemberEntity_.PERSON_ID),
            vis.get("id"),
            vis.get("countryCode"),
            vis.get("dateFrom"),
            vis.get("dateTo"),
            vis.get("visaType")
            );
    cq.distinct(true);

    Predicate joinPred = cb.equal(root.get(MemberEntity_.ID), vis.get(VisaEntity_.ID));

    // p1: DATE_TO is null and (pRefDateFrom is null or pRefDateTo is null)
    Predicate p1 = cb.and(
            cb.isNull(vis.get(VisaEntity_.DATE_TO)),
            cb.or(
                    cb.isNull(cb.parameter(LocalDate.class, "pRefDateFrom")),
                    cb.isNull(cb.parameter(LocalDate.class, "pRefDateTo"))));
    // p2: DATE_TO is not null and DATE_TOO between nvl(pRefDateFrom, MinimumLocalDate) and nvl(pRefDateTo, MaximumLocalDate)
    Predicate p2 = cb.and(
            cb.isNotNull(vis.get(VisaEntity_.DATE_TO)),
            cb.between(vis.get(VisaEntity_.DATE_TO),
                        cb.coalesce(cb.parameter(LocalDate.class, "pRefDateFrom"), MIN),
                        cb.coalesce(cb.parameter(LocalDate.class, "pRefDateTo"), MAX)));

    Predicate itemPred = cb.or(p1, p2);

    cq.where(cb.and(joinPred, itemPred));

    TypedQuery<Object[]> q = em.createQuery(cq)
            .setParameter("pRefDateFrom", LocalDate.now())
            .setParameter("pRefDateTo", LocalDate.now().plusMonths(6))
            ;
    
    List<Object[]> mems = q.getResultList();
}

The exception is:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement [Unbekannter Datentyp: "?"
Unknown data type: "?"; SQL statement:
select distinct c1_0.person_id,v1_0.id,v1_0.country,v1_0.date_from,v1_0.date_to,v1_0.visa_type from member_new c1_0,visa_new v1_0 where c1_0.id=v1_0.id and (v1_0.date_to is null and (? is null or ? is null) or v1_0.date_to is not null and v1_0.date_to between coalesce(?,?) and coalesce(?,?)) [50004-214]] [select distinct c1_0.person_id,v1_0.id,v1_0.country,v1_0.date_from,v1_0.date_to,v1_0.visa_type from member_new c1_0,visa_new v1_0 where c1_0.id=v1_0.id and (v1_0.date_to is null and (? is null or ? is null) or v1_0.date_to is not null and v1_0.date_to between coalesce(?,?) and coalesce(?,?))]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.lambda$list$0(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:518)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:119)
    at com.harry.potter.select.api.ParameterProvisionTest.testLocalDateParameter(ParameterProvisionTest.java:219)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Unbekannter Datentyp: "?"
Unknown data type: "?"; SQL statement:
select distinct c1_0.person_id,v1_0.id,v1_0.country,v1_0.date_from,v1_0.date_to,v1_0.visa_type from member_new c1_0,visa_new v1_0 where c1_0.id=v1_0.id and (v1_0.date_to is null and (? is null or ? is null) or v1_0.date_to is not null and v1_0.date_to between coalesce(?,?) and coalesce(?,?)) [50004-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:554)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.value.TypeInfo.getHigherType(TypeInfo.java:543)
    at org.h2.expression.function.CoalesceFunction.optimize(CoalesceFunction.java:96)
    at org.h2.expression.condition.BetweenPredicate.optimize(BetweenPredicate.java:71)
    at org.h2.expression.condition.ConditionAndOr.optimize(ConditionAndOr.java:137)
    at org.h2.expression.condition.ConditionAndOr.optimize(ConditionAndOr.java:137)
    at org.h2.expression.condition.ConditionAndOr.optimize(ConditionAndOr.java:137)
    at org.h2.expression.Expression.optimizeCondition(Expression.java:148)
    at org.h2.command.query.Select.prepareExpressions(Select.java:1177)
    at org.h2.command.query.Query.prepare(Query.java:218)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:575)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:327)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:177)
    ... 89 more

What has changed and how to recover? Any help would be appreciated.

H2 compiles prepared statements immediately for performance reasons when data types of parameters aren't known yet. When parameters are used inside some expressions an explicit cast is required (CAST(? AS dataType) in SQL or cast(:parameter as dataType) in HQL).

@EvgenijRyazanov: These are named parameters. Replacement should occure even without knowing/checking types. Is there a cast function in Criteria Select API? I guess H2 is having a bug because it worked perfectly in previous versions.

Old versions of H2 may incorrectly convert values of any data type to CHARACTER VARYING data type in COALESCE with parameters, modern versions don't do that because such conversion can corrupt some values. Criteria API has as(Class) method, you can try to use it.
